# How to CSS transition height of P tag when text is updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph tag on a site in which I replace the contents of when a button is clicked (using Javascript) (ie: replace quote #1 with quote #2). I'm not simply expanding on the current text, sometimes the new text may be less than the current text, sometimes more.

In some cases, the text goes from a short about to a longer amount which causes a rather jerky movement on the site as the `<p>` tag increases it's height instantly.

I thought by adding a css transition of 2s might fix it, but it has no effect:

```
p.my-text {
  transition: 2s;
}
```

Is there is a way to transition the height of a `<p>` tag smoothly when the text is updated?

Comment: Can you add the transition you added ?

Comment: @Béranger done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Comment: no matter how long is your text, you can't animate `height`, you can do that only with `max-height` the max-height will expand the container as height as the text is long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a transition on a `height: auto;`, but instead you can use a transition between a given `max-height`(for instance `0`) and another `max-height` bigger than the one expected. See https://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/ICkwe

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `max-height` value to create a transition on.

Take a look at this code sample.

```js
var paragraph;
(() => {
 paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');
  paragraph.style.maxHeight = paragraph.scrollHeight +  "px";
 setInterval(() => {
  
   paragraph.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor nisl sit amet turpis euismod, sit amet vulputate sem mollis. Duis vitae scelerisque magna, et varius neque. Suspendisse at velit in urna tincidunt pellentesque feugiat non erat. Etiam malesuada sapien sapien, sed finibus orci rhoncus sed. Morbi ultrices scelerisque malesuada. Phasellus non dictum ipsum, sed malesuada lacus. Cras dignissim, lectus vel volutpat vulputate, felis ligula molestie velit, at tempor risus eros et orci. Ut malesuada, libero sit amet imperdiet volutpat, tellus orci tempus enim, in luctus diam mi a enim. Phasellus arcu urna, semper sit amet lobortis non, tempus eget felis. Donec ullamcorper nibh feugiat, porttitor mauris ac, imperdiet mi. Nam lectus felis, efficitur quis turpis non, dignissim feugiat purus.";
  
   paragraph.style.maxHeight = paragraph.scrollHeight +  "px";
  }, 1000);
 
})();
```

```css
#paragraph {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  transition: max-height 2s;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph" >
lorem ipsum dolor
</p>
```

Note that you'll have to add `overflow: hidden`

Comment: This is really close, however, it doesn't work if the text is going from large to small.

Comment: @David If you know the height you can use the `height` property instead of `max-height` and it will works even for large to small. But it won't work for `height:auto`